# Spatial mapping of land use change intensity

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have land cover map for two different time periods 2000 and 2010. I want determine the land use change intensity across space. That is, a spatial distribution/pattern of how the various land use types changes within the two time periods. Which areas/pixels have the highest change. I also want to show the change in ha, i.e. high and low value. Any suggestion on how to go about this using ARCGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use [Raster Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-raster-calculator-works.htm). Once you create a new output, you might want to use some form of [Raster Relcass tools](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-reclass-tools.htm) to classify the results of your first output, depending on what your criteria are.

Comment: yeah, I have tried using the raster calculator but it's not giving me what I want. it showed which areas increased and which areas decreased but what I want is the intensity of the change across space. Areas with higher increase and areas with lower increase. I want something like a grid based change intensities

Comment: Have you tried Focal Statistics?

Comment: Thank you for your response. No I haven't tried that. I am a little new to ArcGIS. I started using ArcGIS just about 3months. Can u explain further? In an article that did/calculated the land use intensity, this is the procedure they claim to use:    "to further calculate the spatial distribution of LUCC intensity, we used sampling blocks (5 × 5 km) to intersect with the land use map, and input the major land use type information into each grid. Finally, the grid-based change intensities were calculated."   BUT I do not seem to understand them. Is it the same as Focal statistics?

Comment: In addition, I am working with a classified land cover data

Comment: Learn about these tools: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-neighborhood-tools.htm